# how to get notification in application on hdmi connection in android

Tags: android

I need help regarding the hdmi port status of Android device.I want my application to be notified on connection through hdmi port of android device or tablet.
As per my searching,there is no android api available to do so but i came across motorola hdmi status api and motorola dual screen api,these seem to work only for motorola device.
Please provide me information on this, and is there any other way to acheive this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Correct, there is no Android API for detection of HDMI presence though some vendors are adding their own API's, like for some Motorola devices. Besides that, you can't do much more since vendor HDMI services on Android devices typically run as OS level services and are not accessible to 3rd party apps.